# Visualising Combinations of Two Arrays

Tags: graphing-functions, python

I am trying to find the optimal value range for two inputs to get the highest output $\frac{A_i-1}{B_i}$.

A = [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, ..., 20]
B = [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, ..., 20]

So, for each combination of $A_i$ and $B_i$, I want to visualise the value of $\frac{A_i-1}{B_i}$. The graph will show the distribution of calculated $\frac{A_i-1}{B_i}$ values, with the given $A_i$ and $B_i$ values.

Hopefully, this makes sense! Thank you for any help!!

**Edit:**
When writing this post, the following was not what I had in mind, but it is one way to express the data—I had in mind a histogram.

The colours represent the different buckets, e.g. 0-0.1. So you can visualise the different combination ranges for each bucket.

[image]